# "Open with" context menu option not remembering my selection and always showing Run no matter what

Tags: release-freya, applications, pantheon-files

This has been annoying me a lot recently. Is there a way to disable the "Run" context menu for some specific mimetypes to make it always "Open with `<insert default application here>`?" For some reason it's not remembering my default application for Lua files.
No matter how many times I hit "Open with" and keep the "Keep as default" option checked, I have to repeat the same thing every time. I don't want to run it, I want to open it!

[image: Blank open with submenu]

I looked up some stuff and tried editing the mimetype section in the applications desktop entry, but that seems to have no effect.
I would appreciate if anyone knows how to change this. By the way, I'm using sublime-text-3 if that matters at all.

Comment: Maybe this will still interest you: ["The executable scripts will always by executed in Pantheon Files when clicked"](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10358/170)

Answer (score 3):

Using scratch-text-editor to write a simple lua script, these are seen as text files.  When marked as "executable" I get the "Run" option, but the "Open With" menu offers text editors. If you do not want to run these files then I suggest you try changing the Properties to remove the "execute" permission. This will stop the "Run" option appearing.