# Ask before running script from Pantheon Files

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

I just switched from Linux Mint (17.3) to elementary OS (0.3.2 Freya).

On Mint, when I double clicked a shell script, I was asked if I wanted to "Run in terminal", "Display", "Cancel" or "Run" the script.
[image: Run Script Dialog]

Now, I constantly execute scripts by accident because I just double click on them. (At least I think they are being executed but without a terminal.)

Is it somehow possible to get a similar question before running a shell script from Pantheon Files?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1669996

Answer (score 5):

From what I can tell this dialogue is built into nemo and caja so no, not from pantheon files. you could try another filebrowser (there's lots), or file a bug on [the bug tracker](https://launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bugs) (seeing this dialogue every day would be my personal hell though so ask for a gsettings key).

In the mean time you could hack around it with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --question --text="Do you wish to run '$1', or display its contents?" \
       --ok-label=Run \
       --cancel-label=Edit

case $? in
    0)pantheon-terminal -e "$1"
    ;;
    1)scratch-text-editor $1
    ;;
esac
```

although I'm not sure it works properly outside of the terminal and I'm not sure of the best way to make it the default way to open shell scripts.

Comment: I just realised that you could use my script as a specimen to add dialogues to your own custom scripts to prevent accidental execution. There's lots more zenity can do, check out the docs. It's a hidden gem present in most linux systems.

Comment: I have [posted an answer](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10358/170) on how your script could be used

Comment: could the script be modified so that the zenity window is dismissed with ESC or close button? as it is both trigger the option to open in text editor

Comment: what does pressing esc or closing the window do now? if it doesn't work there's a problem with the switch statement, add the line `echo $?` after zenity, run the script and press esc, and make a new case for this return value.

Comment: both Esc and the window close button (x) do the same as the cancel label: open in the text editor. -- see my answer under this question on how i used your script

Comment: I have also used the script here: [How to execute .desktop in Files](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10955/170). And here ([Zenity script: dismiss window with close (x) button or Esc](http://askubuntu.com/q/888840/47206)) I have asked how to dismiss window.

Comment: ok, well in that case zenity returns the same value for closing the window and cancelling the action, and can't be fixed without patching zenity, or writing a new dialog either in files or as a separate project.

this is kind of the problem with integrating hacks into your workflow: you can't really get support or bugfixes.

Comment: a workaround is to use `yad` in a similar script (allows to close the window as intended) or to add `--timeout=` after `zenity` and have the window closed after that number of secs, like [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/888859/47206)

Comment: that's pretty neat, I'll edit my solution when I get home.

Comment: the zenity script cannot be used with Pantheon Files (bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1669996) - but can be used with other file managers as indicated in my answer to your present question

Comment: i have granted the bounty to you or it would have gone to waste. on the other hand the question is now off-topic as the issue was confirmed as bug

Answer (score 3):

At present, the only way to choose is to right-click on the script - the context menu will give on option to "Run" or "Open with ...".  The latter should give a list of applications including a text editor.

I could not find a bug raised regarding this at the moment but it seems a reasonable request, so I suggest you raise a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is possible with Pantheon Files, but if you're willing to use the regular Nautilus instead (which is actually very similar to Pantheon Files) there's an easy way to configure it:

- install Nautilus
- to make Nautilus visible in Slingshot follow instructions here: [Why don't certain GNOME apps show in Slingshot?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/why-dont-certain-gnome-apps-show-in-slingshot) (don't get confused, both Pantheon Files and Nautilus will be called "Files" in Slingshot. In my system, Nautilus would be the first of the two icons, I guess because it's sorted alphabetically)
- install the dconf-editor (e.g. via Software Center)

Open dconf and you'll have plenty of settings usually hidden in the system settings. The path is org > gnome > nautilus > preferences. There you'll find an option called "executable-text-activation". Clicking on the value you'll get three options:

- "launch" will directly launch the shell script. This would be your current setting
- "display" will always display the script in a text editor
- "ask" will run the prompt you're familiar to from Mint - this is the option you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

#### The executable scripts will be always executed in Pantheon Files when clicked, no matter the application  set as default for that type of files. (bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1669996).

A solution for what is asked (***avoiding to start scripts when accidentally clicking them***), as suggested in [the answer on Nautilus](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4277/170), is to **use another file manager which has the desired option when manipulating those scripts**.

Creating a `run_zenity.sh` with the script from the [answer on Zenity](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4271/170)

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --question --text="Do you wish to run '$1', or display its contents?" \
       --ok-label=Run \
       --cancel-label=Edit

case $? in
    0)pcmanfm "$1"
    ;;
    1)scratch-text-editor $1
    ;;
esac
```

and a contract file for that

```
gedit ~/.local/share/contractor/runoredit-zenity.contract
```

with a content like

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=RUN OR EDIT
Icon=terminal
MimeType=application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=bash -c '/path/to/the/script/run_zenity.sh %f'
```

you will get a new context menu in Pantheon Files; but that is not very useful, as it only provides options that are already provided by the *Run* and *Open with* entry.

[image]

Anyway, that entry opens the Zenity dialog, which works as expected:

[image]

The zenity dialog script can be added to a `desktop` file (a launcher in `~/.local/share/applications`), and the launcher can be set the default 'application' to be used for all executable scripts in Pantheon Files (so that it shows that dialog and avoid the risk of executing the scripts by accident), but no matter that setting *Pantheon File will always execute a file if it is an executable file. On the other hand that works ok for `.desktop` files*. (See more on that [HERE](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10955/170) and below for Thunar).

---

So, considering other file managers:

### PCManFM

Beside Nautilus already mentioned, an even lighter File Manager, PCManFM provides this by default.

[image]

'Open' will use the default application.

That can be changed in settings

[image]

### Thunar

Unlike PCManFM, Thunar file manager doesn't seem to have that dialog for executable files, but **in Thunar the Zenity script can be made the default application for scripts** as indicated, and then, **when clicking a script  in Thunar the Zenity dialog will appear**. For that, create a `desktop` file:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/run-or-edit.desktop
```

with

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Run or edit
Icon=gedit
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
MimeType=application/x-sh;application/x-executable;
Exec=bash -c '/path/to/the/script/run_zenity.sh %f'
```

Then, no matter the file manager, set the new "application" called ***Run or edit*** the default for script files under a file's properties.

As said, in Pantheon Files that changes nothing, but in Thunar it will open the Zenity dialog when clicking to open a script.

To be sure the ***Run or edit*** app appears in the list when you try to set is as default, you can add these lines

```
application/x-sh=run-or-edit.desktop
application/x-executable=run-or-edit.desktop
```

in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` under `[MIME CACHE]`
and also in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` under `[Default Applications]`.

---

There are a few glitches with that Zenity script: after the dialog is displayed, dismissing it with <kbd>Esc</kbd> or the window close button (x) will still open the file in the text editor. (As it is a 'yes or no' dialog, 'no' is  the text editor.) To improve that behavior look [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/888840/47206).