# Why doesn't Pantheon Files remember default application for scripts?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, applications, script

The executable scripts are always executed if clicked in Pantheon Files, even if the default application to be used is changed for them to a text editor under *Properties-Open with*.

I have noticed this behavior only for executable scripts (while [the opposite happens for desktop files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10952/170).)

(This is also the cause why the system will not [Ask before running script from Pantheon Files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/4256/170).)

Can that me changed?

---

#### Edit after posting this as a bug: [Automatic execution of scripts on click or double click cannot be changed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1669996)  - voted to close.

Comment: I suggest you raise a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files about this so this change can be considered

Comment: @JeremyWootten - https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1669996

Comment: It is probably best to close the question as it does not really have an answer.